# Get the height and weight of a png image

Tags: c, pointers, memory, png

I am trying to get the height and weight of a PNG image using pointers to the locations at both in the PNG file.

I read the memory using `read_image()`, but what I get this way is width: 115200 and height: 115464, but my picture has width: 450; height: 451.

Here is my code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdint.h>
    #include<arpa/inet.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void *read_image( const char *filepath );
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      char *ptr=read_image(argv[1]);
      uint32_t *point1=ptr+17;
      uint32_t *point2=ptr+21;
      uint32_t point1_res=ntohl(*point1);
      uint32_t point2_res=ntohl(*point2);
      printf("\nWidth: %d",point1_res);
      printf("\nHeight: %d",point2_res);
      return 0;
     }
     void *read_image(char *path) {
      int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
      if (fd < 0) {
        return NULL;
      }
      size_t size = 1000;
      size_t offset = 0;
      size_t res;
      char *buff = malloc(size);

      while((res = read(fd, buff + offset, 100)) != 0) {
            offset += res;
            if (offset + 100 > size) {
                    size *= 2;
                    buff = realloc(buff, size);
            }
      }
      close(fd);
      return buff; 
     }
```

There is no problem with my `read_image()` function, I am thinking of `ntohl()`?

Comment: Why the offsets `17` and `21`?

Comment: because of this example of a png file:

Comment: The 17th byte you get by adding 16 to the base address.

Comment: Weight?  Or width?  Weight could be measured in kilograms.  Width in pixels.

Comment: You have an alignment issue. `450` is `0x000001C2` and `115200` is `0x0001C200`. Perhaps one byte off?

Comment: Thank you , guys. I fixed my problem by editing 17 to 16.

Comment: `ptr` is `char*` and `point1` and `point2` are `uint32_t`. Are you sure you that you know, what are you doing there? Also check `void *read_image(char *path)` you declare it as `void *read_image( const char *filepath );`

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`  for the function: `read()` and the function: `close()`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include  <stdio.h>` for the function: `printf()`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <arpa/inet.h>` for the function: `ntohl()`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdint.h>`  for the definition of `uint32_t`

Comment: this kind of statement: `uint32_t *point1=ptr+17;` should be: `uint32_t *point1=(uint32_t*)ptr+17;`  so the compiler knows how to add the `17`

Comment: the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t` not a `size_t`,   The function: `read()` will return a negative number when an I/O error occurs. so this statement: `while((res = read(fd, buff + offset, 100)) != 0)` will continue in the program when such an error occurs.  0 == EOF, <0 == error, >0 == some bytes read

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when calling `realloc()`, always assign the returned value to a temp variable, check the variable for NULL, and if not NULL then assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the original pointer to the allocated memory will be lost, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: BTW: there are struct definitions for .png file headers.  Using those headers would make it much simpler than using some 'magic' numbers (which you have all ready seen, are error prone) for calculating offsets into the .png file

Answer (score 2):

The PNG's width shall be at offset 16, the height at offset 20.

So change this

```
  uint32_t *point1=ptr+17;
  uint32_t *point2=ptr+21;
```

to be

```
  uint32_t *point1=ptr+16;
  uint32_t *point2=ptr+20;
```

<sup>([Details on the PNG format are here.](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/))</sup>

Comment: +1 We have 8 bytes for the signature, plus 8 for the IDAT chunk header (4 bytes for Chunk ID, + 4 bytes for chunk length).